# how can I insert logic in app.get() node.js/express?

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps-api-3

I'm running a node.js server with express.
My server need to do some operations like parse a file log , extract ipAddresses and convert them in coordinates using an external Api. 
This coordinates are using for display a google map in my html/ejs page.

I would like , once I start/refresh the main page using ("/") with the map , call all these operations, and display coordinates through market inside the map.

So my idea was

```
    app.get("/" , function(req,res){
    parsingLog();
    res.render("homepage.ejs")
    })
```

Where parsingLog() is first function and the other ones are concatenated inside that function. At  the end of the cycle , I obtain an array of object with coordinates to pass to frontend javascript to display the map. But with the code inside app.get the code runs , but without results. If I run the code without app.get I obtain all the correct results.
I don't understand what's the problem, unfortunately are my very first serious steps into node.js/express.
Thanks to all who will help me

Comment: If you are calling some external API inside parsingLog function then it must be asynchronious. It seems that your code tries to render homepage.ejs before parsingLog finished running and results are not obtained from log files/external API. This code snippet is not enough to analyze the problem

Comment: I try to do  one thing after you told me that ejs is render before obtaining data. I put  res.render  inside a setTimeout.
           app.get("/" , function(req,res){
           parsingLog();

    setTimeout(
      function () {
        res.render("homepage.ejs");
  
      }, 3000);
  });

And it works well.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
  const log = parsingLog();
  res.send(log)
})
```

This is an express endpoint. Any GET request to main page '/' will fire this function.

HTTP is a request response based web protocol, meaning you generate GET request, and the server (node/Express in your case) will have to send a response back to the client.

Your function only returns a string res.render('stringhere'). If you want to attach the results of your function back to the response and send it back to the client, you need to append the results to res.send as it's pretty much the only place where you carry data.